# Black public IP gets created in Azure ARM

Tags: azure

when i am creating a Public IP object for one of VM's NIC using management portal or Azure ARM powershell then a PUblic Object is created with NO Public IP.

There is NO public IP assigned to the object.

Is there any limitation for Number of Public IP per resource group.

Comment: Do i understand right that there is no error, just nothing is being created?

Comment: yes, just IP object gets created but it does not have any Public IP associated

Comment: please share the powershell you use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is limits on the number of PIPs (Public IPs) per subscription, but I don't believe that the issue in your case.

There are 2 types of PIPs in Azure (ARM): Static, and Dynamic. The default is Dynamic.
Dynamic means that although the PIP resource will be created on demand, it wont be assigned an IP address until it is in use. During the time it is unused, the address will appear as "unassigned".

So either associate that PIP with a NIC and VM, and if you did, try to connect to that VM, or change it's type to static.

More info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [there are limits of public IPs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/). If you have no such amount, and IP can not be added, best way to try to ask support.